# Source code for Linux receiver window auto tuning part

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

I am trying to mathematically match the recevier window size captured by wireshark with the source code of linux, to see what algorithm is used for auto-tuning.

Answer (score 0):

These are good links for understanding:

- http://www.psc.edu/index.php/networking/641-tcp-tune#Linux
- http://www.csm.ornl.gov/~dunigan/netperf/auto.html (see Linux 2.4 auto-tuning)

The window sizes grow by bandwidth need and are controlled by kernel variables based on the amount of kernel memory available.